# Cocoa: Getting the current mouse position on the screen

Tags: cocoa, mouse, position

I need to get the mouse position on the screen on a Mac using Xcode. I have some code that supposedly does that but i always returns x and y as 0:

```
void queryPointer()
{

    NSPoint mouseLoc; 
    mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position

    NSLog(@"Mouse location:");
    NSLog(@"x = %d",  mouseLoc.x);
    NSLog(@"y = %d",  mouseLoc.y);    

}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do you get the current position on the screen?
Also, ultimately that position (saved in a NSPoint) needs to be copied into a CGPoint to be used with another function so i need to get this either as x,y coordinates or translate this.

Comment: Got it:

    CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    point = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);
    NSLog(@"Location? x= %f, y = %f", (float)point.x, (float)point.y);

Comment: I fail to see why your initial code was not working, this code works just lovely for me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
point = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);
CFRelease(ourEvent);
NSLog(@"Location? x= %f, y = %f", (float)point.x, (float)point.y);
```

Comment: Don't forget to release that CGEventRef!

Comment: as marcwan has answered, the example in the question doesn't work because of an error with NSLog, the rest is fine.

Comment: can i get point start point ,end point ,height,width....just like on screen rular

Answer (score 57):

The author's original code does not work because s/he is attempting to print floats out as %d. The correct code would be:

```
NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position
NSLog(@"Mouse location: %f %f", mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y);
```

You don't need to go to Carbon to do this.

Comment: That's Quartz Event Services, not Carbon, but otherwise you're correct: Cocoa will do this job just fine, without creating a CGEvent object.

Comment: Whoops, being a 99% Cocoa guy myself, I'm not all that good with the nomenclature of the stuff underneath.  Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: can i get point start point ,end point ,height,width....just like on screen rular

Answer (score 16):

Beware mixing the NS environment with the CG environment.  If you get the mouse location with the NS mouseLocation method then use CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(cgPoint) you will not be sent to the point on the screen you expected.  The problem results from CG using top left as (0,0) while NS uses bottom left as (0,0).

Comment: can i get point start point ,end point ,height,width....just like on screen rular

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question in **Swift**

```
let currentMouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation()
let xPosition = currentMouseLocation.x
let yPosition = currentMouseLocation.y
```

Comment: Pos from topLeft: CGPoint(NSEvent.mouseLocation().x,abs(NSEvent.mouseLocation().y + -NSScreen.mainScreen()!.visibleFrame.height))

Comment: @Andre How can I get informed every time the `mouseLocation` did changed?

Comment: @ixany You would need to implement the events mouseDragged, mouseEntered, and mouseExited. This will work for the window of the application itself.

Comment: FYI, in case you have an NSEvent event source and need CG coordinates, I was able to convert to GCEvent coordinates with the following: `let mouseLocEvent = CGEvent.init(source: eventSource); return mouseLocEvent!.location`.  In my case, this prevented the mouse from teleporting positions.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromPoint(point));
```

NSLog is true;