# Getting "global" mouse position in Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-foundation

How can I get in Mac OS X "global" mouse position - I mean how can I in cocoa/cf/whatever find out cursor position even if it's outside the window, and even if my window is inactive?

I know it's somehow possible (even without admin permissions), because I've seen something like that in Java - but I want to write it in ObjC

Sorry for my English - I hope you'll understand what I mean ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117065/cocoa-getting-the-current-mouse-position-on-the-screen

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
NSPoint mouseLoc;
mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get current mouse position
NSLog(@"Mouse location: %f %f", mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y);
```

If you want it to continuously get the coordinates then make sure you have an NSTimer or something similar

Comment: wow, thanks! I didn't know it's that simple. I thought NSEvent would give me only in-window mouse position. I will accept your answer tommorow, after I'll test it works in the way I want to.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to find out which screen is the mouse located in?

Comment: @adib - use [NSScreen screens] and iterate through the result, using NSPointInRect to test

Comment: can i get point start point ,end point ,height,width....just like on screen rular

Answer (score 29):

Matt S. is correct that if you can use the `NSEvent` API to get the mouse location.  However,  you don't have to poll in order to continuously get coordinates.  You can use a `CGEventTap` instead:

```
- (void) startEventTap {
    //eventTap is an ivar on this class of type CFMachPortRef
    eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, myCGEventCallback, NULL);
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
}

CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    if (type == kCGEventMouseMoved) {
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromPoint([NSEvent mouseLocation]));
    }

    return event;
}
```

This way, your function `myCGEventCallback` will fire every time the mouse moves (regardless of whether your app is frontmost or not), without you having to poll for the information.  Don't forget to `CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, false)` and `CFRelease(eventTap)` when you're done.

Comment: I like this method :)  It's much better then mine

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( I have no idea why, no output appeared.

Comment: ok, never mind. Your solution is probably better, but it doesn't work. I'll just use [NSEvent mouseLocation] ;) Thanks anyway

Comment: @radex it requires having an run loop in place.

Comment: I'd love to see a fleshed out version of this answer for us Objective-C noobs. Run loop? Why doesn't the 'CGEventRef...' part need the "-(void)" etc?

Comment: @cksubs because CGEventRef is a function rather than a method.  Basically, it's a 'C' thing, rather than 'Objective-C' - it's lower level and has different sytax.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate), `kCGHIDEventTap` requires root privileges, which may be why it isn't working for you.  You may want to use `kCGSessionEventTap` instead.

Answer (score 10):

If you're not in cocoa land and an event tap is not appropriate for the situation,

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(nil);
CGPoint loc = CGEventGetLocation(event);
CFRelease(event);
```

works.

Answer (score 4):

For a continuous update on the global cursor position, here is what the code looks like (Swift 4.0.3):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.mouseMoved, handler: {(mouseEvent:NSEvent) in
        let position = mouseEvent.locationInWindow
    })
}
```

Note, the variable 'position' is an NSPoint object with x and y coordinates (among many other attributes). This will not return the coordinates if your application is in focus or when you are clicking and dragging. There are separate events for all of those: simply change the NSEvent.EventTypeMask.mouseMoved to a different EventTypeMask

Answer (score 3):

Matt is correct, but in order to continuously get the coordinates, I believe the other option is to use event monitor provided by `NSEvent`. Try `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`. Check [NSEvent Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/) for more detail.