# Getting cursor position on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, position, cross-platform, mouse-cursor

I want to get the cursor position. Is there any standard function for this?

I'm trying to make my program in C++. I'd like to avoid Cocoa. Not that I have anything against it, but I'd like to make my program cross-platform.

Comment: Which cursor? The text input cursor? The mouse cursor? What application? Globally? Details son!

Comment: This kind of thing is entirely dependent on the OS SDK. Unless you are willing to use 3rd party libraries, there's no cross-platform way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "global" mouse position in Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262516/getting-global-mouse-position-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @karlphillip: It's not really a duplicate, this poster wants an answer that doesn't use Objective-C, whereas that poster explicitly requested Objective-C.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following Core Graphics API, in `CGEvent.h`:

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(NULL);
CGPoint cursor = CGEventGetLocation(event);
CFRelease(event);
```

(Note that you can still use Cocoa in a cross-platform program, you just need to separate platform-specific code into different files instead of using `#define`s.)

Comment: Yeah OP, there's no reason to avoid Cocoa. Using this code requires you use the Core Graphics API, which is OS X only, no different than Cocoa.