# How do you get the position of the mouse on screen with C# in MacOS?

Tags: c#, macos

Without using Cocoa/XCode, is there a way I can get the position of the mouse cursor in C# (MacOS)? It needs to be Unity-Compatible.

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also do you have code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I do not know how to approach this question, hence why I am asking. Is there anything wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject particle;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray))
                Instantiate(particle, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

or taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999239/12808204

```
//the object to move
public Transform objectToMove;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    Ray castPoint = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mouse);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(castPoint, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        objectToMove.transform.position = hit.point;
    }
}
```

Or if you're looking for more specifically an OS API implementation, not necessarily for unity, check [Getting "global" mouse position in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262516/getting-global-mouse-position-in-mac-os-x)
Not to be that guy, but at least try to google it before making a question thread. These where all top google results.

Comment: I saw that exact thread, however, it does use cocoa which I can't use in my unity project. I do want the global mouse position, which is not what the unity Input.mousePosition returns.