# Opposit of CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I am looking for a way to retrieve the cursor position to later set the position back with [CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint). I can't find any function like CGDisplayGetCursorPosition in Quartz Display References.

Does anybody know how to retrieve the (absolute) position of the cursor in Mac OS X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa: Getting the current mouse position on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117065/cocoa-getting-the-current-mouse-position-on-the-screen)

Comment: Hello Rob, do you know if NSPosition compatible to Core Graphics structures?

Comment: There is no `NSPosition`.  If you mean `NSPoint`: if you are building a 64-bit app, `NSPoint` is a typedef for `CGPoint`.  [NSPoint documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW20)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Okay, then this is a duplicate, I am sorry.

Comment: But there is no way to get the CGDirectDisplayID when using [NSEvent mouseLocation]. So this is no solution for my problem. Still needing an answer...

Comment: I'd say that's really a separate question, but I'll give it to you for free. ;^) [CGGetDisplaysWithPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-F17116)

Comment: Well, your question was “retrieve the (absolute) position of the cursor in Mac OS X”.  Anyway, the same page lists the `CGDisplayBounds` function, which provides sufficient information to convert a global point to a screen-local point or vice versa.  Or maybe you want just to use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` instead of `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint`, since that takes a global point, not a screen-local point.

Comment: I've undeleted and revised my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the answers at [Cocoa: Getting the current mouse position on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117065/cocoa-getting-the-current-mouse-position-on-the-screen) to get the mouse position in global coordinates.

To call `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint`, get the display containing that position using `CGGetDisplaysWithPoint`, and then use the rect returned by `CGDisplayBounds` to convert the global point to a screen-local point.

Or just use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` instead of `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint`, since `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` just takes a global point and no display.

Comment: When I store the position of `[NSEvent mouseLocation];` and then `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` to the location cursor doesn't jump to the same position. Instead (when for example mouse was on the top of the screen it now jumps to the bottom). When repeating this (storing new location and jump to the new location) it jumps back to the original position.

Comment: I fixed it by using
    `CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    CGPoint *mouseLocation = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);` instead of `[NSEvent mouseLocation]`. It looks like CG and NS frameworks use inverted coordinates system.