# Getting exact location of cursor in a uitextview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I get the exact position of the cursor in a UITextview in iPhone.  I know that the location of the cursor can be get by using 
                'text_view.selectedRange.location'.
   I want the X and Y co-ordinates of the cursor. How can I do this?

Comment: Might be a good place to start:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117065/cocoa-getting-the-current-mouse-position-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPoint origin = myTextView.frame.origin;
NSString* myHead = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:textView.selectedRange.location];
CGSize initialSize = [myHead sizeWithFont:myTextView.font constrainedToSize:myTextView.contentSize];
NSUInteger startOfLine = [myHead length];
while (startOfLine > 0) {
    /*
     * 1. Adjust startOfLine to the beginning of the first word before startOfLine
     * 2. Check if drawing the substring of head up to startOfLine causes a reduction in height compared to initialSize.
     * 3. If so, then you've identified the start of the line containing the cursor, otherwise keep going.
     */
}

NSString* textTailSection = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
CGSize lineTotalSize = [textTailSection sizeWithFont:myTextView.font forWidth:myTextView.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGPoint cursorPoint = origin;
cursorPoint.x += lineTotalSize.width;
cursorPoint.y += initialSize.height - lineTotalSize.height;
```

**cursorPoint** contains the point.